# How to build a module which calls a JS file on one certain node?

Tags: 7, hooks, javascript

There’s one site (A) which via an API of one other Drupal site (B) gets an already rendered views block displayed on one node - finally with hook_menu() and hook_block_view(). So now I have that node (/stuff) here with it’s views rows and views fields containers.

Since these things really have nothing to do with (B) (where I also don’t have access to) I want to build a module (button) on (A) which calls a JS to manipulate the DOM only on /stuff. Which hooks and syntax will I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like `hook_page_alter()` + `drupal_add_js()`, e.g.

```
function MYMODULE_page_alter(&$page) {
  // Check that we're on the right page.
  if (arg(0) == 'stuff' && !arg(1)) {
    // And add some JS.
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'MYMODULE') . '/MYMODULE.js');
  }
}
```

This could also be done in `hook_preprocess_page()`, `hook_init()`, and probably a bunch of other places. I chose `hook_page_alter()` at random out of those, each should be equally effective.

Comment: That helped! Is it possible that `arg()` doesn't work with aliases? I only got it working with `arg(0) == 'node' && arg(1) == '1234'`, where '1234' stands for the nid.